# Calculate the limit: $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin{\frac{k\pi}n}}{n}$ Using definite integral between the interval $[0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Calculate the limit: $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin{\frac{k\pi}n}}{n}$ Using definite integral between the interval $[0,1]$.

It seems to me like a Riemann integral definition:

$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin{\frac{k\pi}{n}}}{n}=\frac1n(\sin{\frac{\pi}n}+...+\sin\pi)$

So $\Delta x=\frac 1n$ and $f(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi x}n)$ (Not sure about $f(x))$

How do i proceed from this point?

Comment: You're absolutely on the right track.  The point now is to realize this as a Riemann sum of *what* function?  The limit should then be the value of that integral, which can be evaluated using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideas: take the partition $\,P_n\,$ of the unit interval

$$P_n:=\left\{0=x_0\,,\,x_1=\frac1n\,,\ldots,\,x_k=\frac kn\,,\ldots,\,x_n=\frac nn=1\right\}$$

and choose points

$$c_i:=\frac in\;,\;\;1\le i\le n$$

Since **we already know**  that $\,\sin \pi x\,$ is continuous everywhere and Riemann integrable in any closed, finite interval, we can apply the Riemann integral definition for the particular partitions and particular points $\,c_i\,$ as above in each subinterval, and get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n \sin\frac{\pi k}n=\int\limits_0^1 \sin\pi x\,dx=\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: I think i got it, Thanks.

Comment: Any time, @TheAlchemist

Comment: @DonAntonio The clarity and brevity of your answer was very good.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro), $$\sum_{1\le r\le n}\sin \frac{\pi r}n=\frac{\sin \left( n\cdot \frac{\pi}{2n}\right)}{\sin \frac \pi{2n}}\cdot \sin \left(\frac{2\frac\pi n+(n-1)\frac{\pi}n}2\right)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{2n}\right)}{\sin \frac \pi{2n}}$$

Now, $\sin\left(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{2n}\right)=\sin\left(\frac\pi2+\frac\pi{2n}\right)=\cos \frac\pi{2n}\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{(n+1)\pi}{2n}\right)=1$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1{n\sin \frac \pi{2n}}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac {2h}{\pi\sin h }(\text{ putting } \frac \pi{2n}=h)$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1{n\sin \frac \pi{2n}}=\frac2\pi\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac h{\sin h }=\frac2\pi$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't use the definite integral as asked.

Comment: @TheAlchemist: And that makes it a special proof.

Comment: @TheAlchemist, do you know how to calculate definite integral from the definition , not as anti-derivative

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305905/whats-the-justification-for-defining-the-definite-integral-using-a-countably

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem that requires proper handling of the concept of Riemann sum and its relationship to definite integral. Consider the following partition of the interval $[0,1]$:
$$
\mathscr{P}\Big( [0,1]\Big)=\left \{ 0=x_0<x_1=\frac{1}{n}<\ldots < x_k=k\cdot \frac{1}{n}<\ldots<x_{n}=n\cdot\frac{1}{n} \right\}
$$
chose $x^*_k\in [x_{k-1},x_{k}]$ equal to $k\cdot \frac{1}{n}$ and set $\Delta x_k=x_k-x_{k-1}$ .
Then we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\inf_{\xi\in[x_k,x_{k-1}]}\sin( \xi\pi)\cdot\Delta x_k
\leq
 \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin( x_k^*\pi)\cdot\Delta x_k
\leq
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sup_{\xi\in[x_k,x_{k-1}]}\sin( \xi\pi)\cdot\Delta x_k
$$
that is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\inf_{\xi\in[x_k,x_{k-1}]}\sin( \xi\pi)\cdot\Delta x_k
\leq
\sum_{k=1}^n\sin{\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right )}\frac{1}{n}
\leq
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sup_{\xi\in[x_k,x_{k-1}]}\sin( \xi \pi)\cdot\Delta x_k.
$$
If we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\inf_{\xi\in[x_k,x_{k-1}]}\sin( \xi \pi)\cdot\Delta x_k
=
 \int_0^1\sin( x\pi)dx
=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sup_{\xi\in[x_k,x_{k-1}]}\sin( \xi\pi)\cdot\Delta x_k
$$
then 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\sin{\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right )}\frac{1}{n}=
 \int_0^1\sin( x\pi)dx
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be 
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\sin \pi xdx=\frac{2}{\pi}
$$

EDIT OK, the point here is the direct implementation of Riemanns sums with $d x = \frac{b-a}{n}, \ b=1, \ a=0$ and $\frac{k}{n}=x$

Comment: How do you know? I mean, How did you understand that is the function you need to find?

Comment: set $x=\frac{k}{n}$ to get lower and upper bounds

Comment: So, Shouldn't they be 0 and +1? And, By setting $x=\frac kn$ you mean i always take the right part of the squares?

Comment: Agree, $x=1$ if $k=n$. Sorry about the mistake.

Comment: I don't see the *total* purpose of down-voting? Rather than correcting just the $-1$ part, why the down vote? (+1) anyway.

Comment: Some people just can't wait to downvote instead of trying to give advice, to point the mistake, etc. Anyway, as this answer's lacking all explanation I can't upvote it, but I would never downvote it.

Comment: OK I added an edit. Sorry about the mess. I do find other answere more substantial and to the point.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that if $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is some function we can define the Riemann Sum of $f$ in the interval by choosing a partition $P = \{t_0, \dots, t_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ in a very specific manner: we simply divide the interval $[a,b]$ equally calculating it's length $b-a$ and then dividing by the number of subintervals that we want. So a partition with $n$ subintervals will have $t_i = a + i\Delta t$ where $\Delta t = (b-a)/n$ is the size of each interval. In that case the integral of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ will be the limit:

$$\int_a^b f(t)dt=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i)\Delta t$$

Look that in your case we are working on the interval $[0,1]$ so for a partition of $n$ subintervals we'll have $\Delta t = 1/n$. Now we want to compute the limit of the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\sin{\left(\frac{i\pi}{n}\right)}$$

Note that with this we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta t\sin{\left(i\Delta t \pi\right)}$$

However, since the interval starts on $0$ and since $t_i = a + i\Delta t$, we have that $t_i = i\Delta t$, so we have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sin{\left(t_i \pi\right)}\Delta t$$

Now on the limit this will become obviously the following integral:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \sin{\left(t_i \pi\right)}\Delta t=\int_0^1 \sin(\pi t)dt$$

This integral is computed trivially by setting $u=\pi t$, $dt=du/\pi$ and so $u$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi$ and we have:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \sin{\left(t_i \pi\right)}\Delta t=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin(u)du=\frac{2}{\pi}$$